# 'Tip of Iceberg': negative meaning?

Tags: idioms, connotation, idiom-meaning, reference

I want to use 'tip of iceberg' in a recommendation letter. In particular, I give an anecdote which illustrated that this person is very diligent and skillful. Then I say "such instance is merely a tip of iceberg, throughout the entire 5 years, I have witness many demonstrations of high level performance of so and so....."

Am I using the phrase correctly? Does 'tip of iceberg' usually associate with negative meaning?

From a webpage, it says that:

> The phrase “tip of the iceberg” is used to refer to a situation in
>   which you or someone else is seeing only a small part of what is
>   really a bigger problem. So, the iceberg is used to refer to the fact
>   that there is a very big problem, and the “tip” is a small part of
>   that iceberg, or a small part of the bigger problem. The phrase has a
>   negative meaning to it – and is usually used to describe situations or
>   people that are difficult.

Comment: It **most commonly** has a negative meaning, but in context it can be used for positive things as well. If you say that a positive thing about someone is just the tip of the iceberg [note: not “a tip of iceberg”—the phrase is “_the_ tip of _the_ iceberg] and then follow up with other good things about that person, no one will misunderstand or think it strange.

Comment: The problem, as far as I can tell, is that it is the submerged part of the iceberg that sinks the big ships. I think that is where the negative meaning comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is there anything that's similar but definitely positive phrase that I can use? I am writing a reference letter for someone. Thanks!

Comment: "These nuggets only hint at the great things I expect from ___." Or "...such instances are merely small representations of Pat's diligence and skill. Throughout our five years of working together, I have witnessed many such demonstrations of high-level performance."

Comment: "there is much more to him than that" is a valid substitute, but no one is going to misunderstand if you follow up with other good things as examples. "To name just a few...", "Brevity dictates I summarize, but...", "It would be impossible to fully convey the merits/value of...", etc. may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ***[expression](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/meaning-and-origin-of-the-idiom-tip-of-the-iceberg.html)*** is mainly associated with problems, difficult issues:

> - ***According to Merriam-Webster, the idiom means "the earliest, most obvious, or most superficial manifestation of some phenomenon."*** The phenomenon, like the submerged part of the iceberg, is always larger is size that one can perceive. What is perceived is just the trivial appearance.
> - ***The idiom is used to refer to a situation or problem, which is anticipated as small in effect, but its larger part is hidden.*** One may not able to take in the whole problem or the situation, just like it is harder to guess the size of the underwater portion of the iceberg. The tip is just a small part of the bigger problem.
> - ***The idiom has a negative connotation to it as it is used to warn that there is more to the situation or the problem than what is visible.***  The expression can be used to describe a person who difficult to figure out as well.

(www.buzzle.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is there anything that's similar but definitely positive phrase that I can use? I am writing a reference letter for someone. Thanks! –

Comment: Personally I would not use "tip of the iceberg" in your case. You may say: " the anecdote  is just a small example of how diligent and skilful the candidate actually is.

Comment: What Josh said.

Comment: Or "one of many examples" if you don't want to diminish the significance of the particular example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say maybe go for "That merely ***scratches the surface***" of what they are capable of.

That idiom seems to have more positive connotations with it.